# Qt fire different signal depending on parameter type

Tags: c++, qt, polymorphism, signals

I need to fire different signal from SomeClass::fireSignal member function depending on it parameters type. The solution I see is to use Qt meta system. Is there more correct solution for such task? Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
class SomeClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void fireSignal(BaseClass *param) {
        if(param->metaObject->className() == "DerivedClass1") {
            emit derivedClass1Signal(param)
        }
        if(param->metaObject->className() == "SecondDerivedClass") {
            emit secondDerivedClassSignal(param)
        }
        if(param->metaObject->className() == "OtherDerivedClass") {
            emit otherDerivedClassSignal(param)
        }
    }
signals:
    void derivedClass1Signal(DerivedClass1 *param);
    void secondDerivedClassSignal(SecondDerivedClass *param);
    void otherDerivedClassSignal(OtherDerivedClass *param)
};
```

Comment: Is the `BaseClass` hierarchy all your own? If it is, you could use the visitor pattern (a.k.a. double dispatch).

Comment: @mol, that will not work if each signal is connected to different slots individually

Comment: @molbnilo, could you describe how it could be accomplished?

Comment: @Singer, yes I need connect my signals to different slots.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
class SomeClass : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
void fireSignal(BaseClass *param) {
    if(param->metaObject->className() == DerivedCass::staticMetaObject.className()) {
        emit sig(qobject_cast<DerivedClass*>(param);
    }
    if(param->metaObject->className() == SecondDerivedClass::staticMetaObject.className()) {
        emit sig(qobject_cast<SecondDerivedClass*>(param);
    }
    if(param->metaObject->className() == OtherDerivedClass::staticMetaObject.className()) {
        emit sig(qobject_cast<OtherDerivedClass*>(param);
    }
}
signals:
    void sig(DerivedClass1 *param);
    void sig(SecondDerivedClass *param);
    void sig(OtherDerivedClass *param)
};
```

Comment: Might run into a problem comparing const char* for class name, if so, make QStrings out of them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this is Ok. You can make some improvements, but that will heavilly depend on how you are using these signals. For example, if all three are connected to the same slot(s), you can reduce your code here, leaving one signal that has one argument which is a pointer of a base class:

```
class SomeClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void fireSignal(BaseClass *param) {
            emit derivedClassSignal(param);
    }
signals:
    void derivedClassSignal(DerivedClass1 *param);
};
```

However, removing the check from the sender's code will force you to include it into the receiver's code (i.e. the check for which exact derived type was passed). If, however, each signal is connected to a different slot, and those slots require only a specific type of argument, this will not work, and your approach will be better.

Comment: Thanks. I need to connect signals to different slots.

Comment: Could I have in BaseClass some virtual member function that will return pointer to correct signal and  will be overriden in derived classes?